# How Can I Create Folders in the Installation Process?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I haven't deployed the application yet. I'm new to this, how can i create folders under C:\Programs Files during installation? Should i put the snippet of creating folders in program.cs?

The application is Winform in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Setup project to your Solution And then add Primary output and all the files needed.
From the Property windows of the setup project you can choose default location where to save
your projects which I usually do in my projects.
Refer this for more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235317%28VS.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio, use the MSI Installer Wizard template to add an Installer to your solution.

Using this template you can set up the appropriate folders (also registry keys, start menu shortcuts etc.) to create when you deploy your project.

In Visual Studio 2008 this template is under Other Project Types->Setup and Deployment->Setup Wizard.

Answer (score 2):

Use deployment (setup) project. it will create this folder for you

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) over the visual studio deployment project. It has a bit of a learning curve, but it's worth learning it.